# Slow query with where,group by, order by (using filesort)

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by, query-optimization

Hi i have trouble with optimizing a query.
I have reduced the original query (~2 seconds) to this (0.3s):

```
SELECT kunden.id, kunden.Typ, cache.bestellungen_count 
FROM cache
INNER JOIN kunden ON kunden.id=cache.kunde_id
WHERE kunden.kundentyp=1 
GROUP BY kunden.id  
--  ORDER BY kunden.id DESC
ORDER BY cache.bestellungen_gesamtbetrag DESC
LIMIT 0,500
```

explain shows that a filesort is used.

```
select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra   
SIMPLE  kunden  ref     PRIMARY,kundentyp,id_k...   kundentyp   4   const   26235   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
SIMPLE  cache   ref     kunde_id,kunde_id_gesamtbetrag  kunde_id    4   partyschnaps.kunden.indexh  1   Using index condition
```

I guess the Problem is that where, group and order by cannot all use a Index, so when i order by kunden.id the performance boosts by factor of ~30 (0.01s) and everything can be solved by index.

Index on cache table for the order by column and a combined one for the FK kunden_id and order by column have no effect.

Comment: Well i found a workaround for the original query by doing the where/limit first in a subselect so the group by/order by filesort has only to handle 500 rows instead of tens of thousands. This way the query time is reduced from 2s to 0.07s. But obviously this query is not very flexible and so i will have to change it to achieve other sorting/filtering conditions. `SELECT ... FROM (SELECT * FROM cache WHERE kundentyp=1 ORDER BY bestellungen_gesamtbetrag DESC) as cache INNER JOIN kunden ... GROUP BY kunden.id ORDER BY cache.bestellungen_gesamtbetrag DESC`

Comment: Well you can do is put everything you want in temp table without order by clause and later on query temp table based on order by clause. This should help you.

Comment: I think i cant do that - what i want depends on the sorting, for example the first 500 customers by their revenue. Copyying all customers in a temp table obviously makes no sense and without sorting i cant tell which 500 i want and thats exactly what makes the query slow